# To get Oracle server Version from a windows server

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to get Oracle Server version number from a Windows server using PowerShell command mainly from Registry. I have got the command to get it from the inventory.xml file. However, for this, I need to scan the particular directory and get the value. It's taking a lot of time and so performance getting reduced. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just hit the uninstall registry keys. That is where the info is most reliably real.
No different than any other software inventory effort. The below show examples. Note avoid using the Win32Product this as it's really slow and impacts the effort sort of negatively, stick with the registry.

```
# registry locations where installed software is logged
$pathAllUser = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
$pathCurrentUser = "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
$pathAllUser32 = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
$pathCurrentUser32 = "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
```

> Get-RemoteProgram Get list of installed programs on remote or local
>   computer
>
> This script generates a list by querying the registry and returning
>   the installed programs of a local or remote computer. It allows for
>   retrieval of additional properties such as the uninstall string of an
>   application as well.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RemoteProgram-Get-list-de9fd2b4
>
> Create “Software Inventory of Remote Machines” in HTML File using
>   PowerShell
>
> Note: Please Treat this script as education purpose, dont run it on
>   your production environmnet. this script is using Win32_product WMI
>   class and that calls MSI to get the list of the software and sometime
>   MSIstarting recofiguring softwares Please see this link
>   http://support.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Software-Inventory-of-f66b5bdc
>
> Powershell : Server's remote inventory
>
> Create a inventory of servers remotely in powershell.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Servers-remote-fff0d4a9